# Hide physical "Webpages" folder using MapPageRoute when browsing around website

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, asp.net-routing

How do I hide the physical directory folder "Webpages" in the web-browser URL path & hyperlink url path when browsing the webpages?  The RouteConfig I'm looking at is...

Let's say instead of this

```
https://www.foo.com/Webpages/SignIn.aspx
https://www.foo.com/Webpages/MemberReport.aspx
https://www.foo.com/Webpages/Admin/ManagerReport.aspx
https://www.foo.com/Webpages/UserAccount.cshtml
https://www.foo.com/Webpages/SavedValues.cshtml
```

But works like this...

```
https://www.foo.com/SignIn.aspx
https://www.foo.com/MemberReport.aspx
https://www.foo.com/Admin/ManagerReport.aspx
https://www.foo.com/UserAccount.cshtml
https://www.foo.com/SavedValues.cshtml
```

having this physical directory path

```
X:\inetpub\Foo\Webpages\SignIn.aspx
X:\inetpub\Foo\Webpages\MemberReport.aspx
X:\inetpub\Foo\Webpages\Admin\ManagerReport.aspx
X:\inetpub\Foo\Webpages\UserAccount.cshtml
X:\inetpub\Foo\Webpages\SavedValues.cshtml
```

where I can do this clickable hyperlink nagivation as

SignIn.aspx
   MemberReport.aspx
   Admin\ManagerReport.aspx
   UserAccount.cshtml
   SavedValues.cshtml

```
namespace Dealer.WebApp.Mobile
{
  public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "", "~/Webpages/SignIn.aspx");            
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using routes.MapPageRoute("route_0","{*fullpath}","~Webpages/{*fullpath}"); seems to work ok but now images, css, javascripts doesn't work.   Hmm..

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what specifically is not working? Only with this information can folks provide useful feedback and answers.